# How to profile Monotouch to see count of trampolines (by type) being created at runtime?

Tags: ios, generics, xamarin.ios, profiling, anonymous-methods

There are quite a few posts regarding type 0, type 1 and type 2 trampolines and the runtime error of

> "ran out of trampolines"

on iOS devices.

I've got a good understanding of how to increase the number of the different trampoline types during the AOT cross-compile, however, I'm becoming wary of arbitrarily increasing the allocations whenever we run into the ceiling during runtime.

I recently added a component that receives several `Func<>` arguments, and the majority of consumers of the component are creating the `Func<>` delegates anonymously.  My assumption was that although I could expect that each anonymous delegate would result in the creation of a trampoline, the behavior I seem to be observing is that instead of reusing that trampoline, it continues to create type 0 (ntrampoline [method trampolines?] every time the anon delegate is executed.

What would be extremely helpful is a tool or an api call that would allow me to monitor, log or profile the application at runtime to observe trampoline creation.

Any guidance on side effects of either exposing a generic delegate or anonymous delegate usage would also be appreciated.

Thanks for any tips in the right direction.

Regards,
Kevin Ferron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to ask such (very specific) questions to the [mono-devel](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-devel-list) mailing list, i.e. there's several questions (and suggestions wrt profiling) that would make it hard to answer here (even if it could be tagged properly).

I assume you have already read the links below (but they might help people wondering about trampolines).

- MonoTouch [Troubleshooting](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting)
- Mono wiki [documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime%3aDocumentation%3aTrampolines) on trampolines
- [Blog entry](http://monoruntime.wordpress.com/2009/04/13/magic-of-trampolines/) that tries to demystify trampolines

You can also get some statistics from Mono using the **--stats** option. E.g.

```
mono --stats myapp.exe

...
JIT statistics
Unwind info size                    : 198
Calls to trampolines                : 626
JIT trampolines                     : 416
Unbox trampolines                   : 1
Static rgctx trampolines            : 1
...
```

However it won't help you in MonoTouch context where AOT is used (many thing differs) and where you don't control the execution of the application.